# Source of method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

In the source code of `Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail` ([API reference](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Mail/PendingMail.html)), the `queue` method references `$this->mailer->queue`. However, `$this->mailer` is an instance of `Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer` ([API reference](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Contracts/Mail/Mailer.html)) which has no `queue` method. So can anyone please explain how this piece of code works if it seemingly calls a method that doesn't exist?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L378

Comment: The actual `Mailer`, `Illuminate\Mail\Mailer`, that gets passed in does have a `queue` method ... welcome to the wonderful world of calling methods that don't exist on interfaces that happens in Laravel often ... the contracts/interfaces end up being more of a "has at least these methods" type of deal often

Answer (score 2):

Contracts is just what Laravel calls Interfaces, it's an interface being implemented by [Illuminate\Mail\Mailer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L378) which does have that method `queue` defined

```php
/**
 * Queue a new e-mail message for sending.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailable  $view
 * @param  string|null  $queue
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function queue($view, $queue = null)
{
    if (! $view instanceof MailableContract) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Only mailables may be queued.');
    }

    if (is_string($queue)) {
        $view->onQueue($queue);
    }

    return $view->queue($this->queue);
}
```

Hope this helps